# Javascript Array not recognized within PHP - Get undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, tooltip

I am rewriting html code that is working into PHP. I am almost there but the final part is to get my tooltips working. The program lists a bunch of activities from an XML file and the schedules for these activities are also in the XML file. The tooltip uses an array to define the schedule for each activity. Putting your mouse over the activity brings up a tooltip with that activity's schedule. The tootip program was written by someone far more capable than I and was available for free and works fine in my original program. The program runs through but the tooltips are all undefined. I know my variables are working properly (though debugging) but I believe array is not as I hoped it would be. Here is a section of the code I created and I will add some of the debugging output. I suspect the array in document.write is not working as I had hoped.

My code

```
echo <<<EOF
     <div id="table">
       <table id="tbloc" border="0" width="100%">


EOF;

      foreach($activities as $activity)
      {
       if ($cycle==1)
       {
         echo '<tr>';
       }
       $act=$activity->column;
       $n = $n+1;
echo <<<EOF

  <script type ="text/javascript">
  var n = $n;
  if (n == 1)
  {
   var A   = new Array();
  }

  A[n] = "$activity->schedule";
  action = "$act";
  document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
  n=n+1;
  </script>
EOF;


            if ($cycle!==4)
            {
            $cycle=$cycle+1;
            }
            else
            {
            $cycle=1;
            echo '</tr>';
            }

     }
?>
```

The debugger output form Explorer

Note: Move Mouse over desired activity to see regular scheduling for that activity

```
     <div id="table">
       <table id="tbloc" border="0" width="100%">

<tr>
  <script type ="text/javascript">
  var n = 1;
  if (n == 1)
  {
   var A   = new Array();
  }

  A[n] = "<b><u>Amateur Radio Schedule:</u></b><br />Wed  11:30am - 1:00pm<br />Wed 6:00pm - 8:30pm";
  action = "Amateur Radio";
  document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
  n=n+1;
  </script>
  <script type ="text/javascript">
  var n = 2;
  if (n == 1)
  {
   var A   = new Array();
  }

  A[n] = "<b><u>Bingo Schedule:</u></b><br />Fri 12:30pm - 3:00pm";
  action = "Bingo";
  document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
  n=n+1;
  </script>
  <script type ="text/javascript">
  var n = 3;
  if (n == 1)
  {
   var A   = new Array();
  }

  A[n] = "<b><u>Book Club Schedule:</u></b><br />Every 2nd Thurs 2:00pm - 3:00pm<br />Every 3rd Mon 1:00pm - 3:00pm";
  action = "Book Club";
  document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
  n=n+1;
  </script>
```

Comment: If you're going to mix PHP with HTML you might find it easier to close and reopen tags `?> HTML <?php ` rather than use `<<<EOF HTML EOF;`

Comment: As for document.write problem, why are you using that? You're writing the HTML in PHP, there's no need to write javascript in PHP that writes HTML on page load. I suggest you get the PHP to output all the HTML required with no javascript at all. Then ask the question again, giving the generated HTML and the source of the tooltip plugin, what you've tried (`onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"`) and someone will probably give you an answer very quickly. Though, having copied that line, I can see a problem: You're outputting `n`, not the number that the variable holds.

Comment: I agree, I recognize I am outputting n not the number, That is the crux of the problem and the question I  am asking - how do I get it to output the array number and not "n".  I will try and recode this piece of code in a more  traditional manner as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting a `<script>` tag inside a `<tr>` which shouldn't be done. The problem you're reporting is in several places where you are outputting the variable names instead of the variables.

```
var n = $n;
```

outputs as exactly that. You mean

```
var n = <?php echo $n; ?>
```

and

```
document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[n])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
```

You are outputting `n` instead of the number it represents. This will write the variable contents instead.

```
document.write('<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A[' + n + '])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'+action+'</b></a></td>');
```

There are many instances in your code, not just those two.

But you need to separate your JS, the smallest change to at least get it valid, though not the ideal solution, would be this:

```
<?php
$table=''; // this will be outputted as one string

foreach($activities as $activity){
    if ($cycle==1){
        $table.= '<tr>';
    }
    $act=$activity->column;
    $n = $n+1;
    ?>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    var n = <?php echo $n; ?>
    if (n == 1){
        var A   = new Array();
    }
    A[n] = <?php echo json_encode($activity->schedule); ?>;
    <?php
        $table.='<td width="25%"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onmouseover="Tip(A['.$n.'])"  onmouseout="UnTip()"><b>'.$act.'</b></a></td>';
    ?>
    n=n+1;
    </script>
    <?php 
} // end foreach (guessing this is where it's meant to end
?>
<div id="table">
<table id="tbloc" border="0" width="100%">
<?php echo $table; ?>
</table>
<?php
```

But, where does `$cycle` come from? There should be a `</tr>` somewhere...

Comment: Sorry about not including $cycle, it comes earlier and counts the number of cells to begin a new row after 4. There is a </tr> further ahead. Table actually works, the only problem is the tooltip. I will study these responses and see if can understand them and if they help me resolve the issue. Thank you all for providing me input, I appreciate your responses.

Comment: I tried your code above and it does not work (I did add in $cycle to get the table to work as I wanted) I get (object OBJECT) when I mouse over the activity and syntax error (Debugger) for the </tr> statement. Obviously, I need to expand my knowledge and experience in this area and you have given me some things to look at to revise my code. Still working on it. Thanks

Comment: Oops, I should add the </tr> was my code for the cycle part and that is now working without syntax errors (for code above). No errors reported when running the code but still get object OBJECT for tootltip. Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: The code isn't complete. I've shown the problem, you need to understand what the difference is and apply it to the rest of your code. It's hard to work out why you get object without seeing the new generated HTML

Comment: I have added the revised HTML along with some debugger excerpts

Comment: I resolved the issue. A lot of digging, googling and trial and error but it is working as I wanted to. I supplied the revised code above for those who may be interested.